# Arduino code Wire ported to Atmel Xplained Mini to communicate with DS3231

Tags: c, arduino, atmega

I am taking Arduino Prototype code used for a DS3231 RTC and taking it to an embedded platform that does not directly support Arduino code (right now that is the Atmel Xplained Mini). Is there a way for me to create an equivalent program without writing an entire I2C protocol and the entire data communication from scratch? There must be an overlapping library/header/code block that I can adapt to my purpose.

As an example I am looking to make the code  [here](http://tronixstuff.com/2014/12/01/tutorial-using-ds1307-and-ds3231-real-time-clock-modules-with-arduino/) work on the Atmel Xplained Board. The code should be pretty simple, what I need is for the DS3231 to tell the MCU the time when it asks for it. I can do the manipulation of the date/time myself, it is getting that information on a non-Arduino platform that is the road block for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino has an existing wiring library that facilitates I2C communication, most professional development frameworks aren't quite so simple but are also more full-featured.  I'm assuming you are using Atmel Studio, you'll want to look at the TWI (two-wire interface) documentation for doing I2C communication.

[AVR315: Using the TWI Module as I2C Master](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2564-Using-the-TWI-Module-as-I2C-Master_ApplicationNote_AVR315.pdf)

You can copy TWI_Master.c and TWI_Master.h to your project and use these for I2C communication.  That is what I've typically done in the past.

The demo code that goes with this app note can be found here, main.c has an example of the usage of this I2C driver:

[AVR315 Demo Code](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-2564-Using-the-TWI-Module-as-I2C-Master_ApplicationNote_AVR315.zip)